# How to deal with binary predictors in a logistic regression model?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I'm building a logistic regression model in R using `glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = train.set, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))`. Among 4 predictors `x1, x2, x3, x4`, they all are categorical. However `x1, x2, x3` are on a scale of 0 to 10, and `x4` is binary (0 or 1).

My question is how should i properly pre-process `x4`? I'm asking because I know it is a really important variables in terms of prediction, but it's showing a pretty low importance in the `summary()` due to the fact that it's on a different scale as the rest of predictors.

Could someone who has experienced similar situation share your approach? Thanks a lot!

edit: all predictors `x1, x2, x3, x4` are factors. I do understand that as long as they are all factors, it shouldn't matter what values each predictors they have. but we expect `x4` to be a more important predictors, but `varImp` shows the opposite.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example ? Also, is `x4`  (as well as the other predictors) a `factor` variable ?

Comment: Your regression will set up dummy variables for the RHS categorical variables. This might help: https://www.r-bloggers.com/regression-on-categorical-variables/

Comment: Just make sure you set your categorical variables as `factor`s.

Comment: How many observations do you have? It's possible you do not have enough for the amount of combinations three 10 level factors and one 2 level factor has.

Answer (score 1):

SJ, if these are all categorical (assuming they are factors) then the scale doesn't really matter.  The logistic regression isn't analyzing the actual number, but rather the presence or absence of that variable.  You could easily rename all of the variables A,B,C,D, etc. within x1, x2, x3, and x4 and you would get the same results because they are categorical.

Comment: Hi Jenks, thanks for your response! I do have all variables as factors. but we just expect `x4` with higher importance.

Comment: There are many reasons for this.  1. Your beliefs may be incorrect 2. like @spazznolo said previously above you may not have enough power 3. Your subset you are measuring is not representative

Answer (score 0):

x1 through x3 are not binary. If they are categorical with 10 categories and not ordinal, you can create 10 indicator variables for the presence or absence of each category.

Comment: Thans @M Waz! Actually, x1 to x3 are ordinal. is converting to factors is the best way?